# ArrayAdapter not working properly, displaying only 1 item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-arrayadapter

I recently learned about ArrayAdapters and am attempting to use one in my current app. I have used the code I learned previously, but I've done something wrong. Instead of displaying the full list, only 1 set in the list is displayed. I'm not sure what I'm missing to make it display the full list.

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#6002EE">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/PageTitle"
        android:text="@string/songs"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list">

        </ListView>

    </ScrollView>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my SongAdapter looks like this:

```
    public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList pWords) {
            super(context,0, pWords);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;

            if(listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            Song my_word = (Song) getItem(position);
            TextView songTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.song);
            songTextView.setText(my_word.getSongTitle());
            TextView artistTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            artistTextView.setText(my_word.getArtist());

            return listItemView;

        }
    }
```

I'm just assuming that's what's needed to help me out. I'm very new. I did read through many pages on ArrayAdapters, many other problems seem to be more complicated than this. I feel like I'm missing some code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the scrollview layout, the only child is the listview itself so it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Show main_activity code, i can't comment that is why i am writing it as an answer. As you are saying it is showing one i think you are only adding one set of list in main_activity class.